# DBCC show_statistics: density doesn't match what I calculate

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've read in several articles that the density of a column is (1.0 / count(distinct columnname)).  I have a column with roughly 2.6 million distinct values over 2.7 million rows, but the column density in DBCC show_statistics even AFTER updating statistics with fullscan is .48.

I am confused as to where this number could be coming from.  Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Are you talking about the density in the `STAT_HEADER`? BOL Says this [isn't used anyway](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174384.aspx)

Comment: BOL says it's not used for 2008 and higher.  I'm on an '05 instance.  But yes that's what I meant.  I think maybe I mistook what that value meant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174384.aspx) for `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS` says that Density (in the header) is:

> *Calculated as 1 / distinct values for all values in the first key column of the statistics object, **excluding the histogram boundary values**.*

It also says:

> *This Density value is not used by the query optimizer and is displayed for backward compatibility with versions before SQL Server 2008.*

You are using SQL Server 2005, so this value may be relevant to you in some circumstances, but I don't know exactly when 2005 would use that Density value.